How to apply conditional formatting to cell depending on data in a known column and the same row as the cell being formatted?
I have a matrix of cells with labels in the upper row (in this example, Stores) and leftmost column (Products). I have a couple of dropdowns that I can use to select a value from these labels (SelectedProduct and SelectedStore). I want to highlight the cell that is in the intersection of the selected column and row.
I tried conditional formatting. I understand that I must provide a formula that returns TRUE for the cells that I want to highlight. I also understand that I must first apply the formatting to the top left corner of the matrix, and then extend the format to the rest by format painter or by editing the range in the rule (as per this superuser answer).
This is the formula I'm currently using:
=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(Stores);COLUMN(C4)))=SelectedStore;INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(C4);COLUMN(Products)))=SelectedProduct)

Where C4 is the top left cell of the range. The formula returns the expected boolean value as I change the referenced cell, and the values of SelectedProduct and SelectedStore outside the context of conditional formatting, but when I use the formula in the rule, it doesn't do anything, even when selecting a single cell for the range.
Below some captures of how it all looks:


I would guess my approach using ADDRESS and INDIRECT doesn't work in that context, but then I wonder what should I do?

AND and OR combined with INDIRECT do not work in conditional formatting, I think because the cell reference cannot be varied inside the range. So the quick fix would be to change your formula to (please replace , with ;):
=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(Stores),COLUMN(C4)))=SelectedStore) *(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(C4),COLUMN(Products)))=SelectedProduct)

There are many other ways, one is using INDEX:
=(INDEX(Stores,,COLUMN(C4))=SelectedStore) 
* (INDEX(Products,ROW(C4)) = SelectedProduct)

BTW, it is very nice you have named your ranges and cells :)

or, as Tom suggested, by defining Product and Store as mixed references:

with B3 selected add name Product, changing $B$3 to $B3
with C2 selected add name Store, changing $C$2 to C$2



Don't use indirect or anything like that, just rely on relative addressing:
=AND(C$3=SelectedStore,$B4=SelectedProduct)

As you move across the range, C$3 will automatically change to D$3 etc. and as you move down the range $B4 will change to $B5 etc.

